# How to maintain a server database?

Tags: database

I am actually trying to build an windows application and I need to maintain a database ("Not local") on cloud where can I actually maintain? I tried using phpmyadmin but it was to create a local db.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SSH in conjunction with a database admin software such as Sequel pro for OSX or MySQL Workbench (http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) for other operating systems.

The most secure way typically would be to connect to the remote database server via SSH. Both these programs have that option available.

So you'd use the ssh key you'd use to SSH into the server, so tunnel into the database via SSH also.